# Logging options for Heroku: Amazon SimpleDB, MongoHQ, other options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I need a robust logging option for my Heroku-hosted app. I will be logging HTTP requests and application errors. I need to filter the logs based on IP, type of request, user agent, time of day, and several other attributes.

I've seen SimpleDB and MongoHQ as recommended solutions for Heroku-hosted apps. Unfortunately, I don't think Heroku's logging utilities are currently adequate for my needs given the limited filtering options.

Most importantly, the solution needs to easy to use and implement. Secondarily, it should be robust. Any advice as to what solution best fits my needs and why?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're implementing a logging solution and your requirements are:

- needs to be able to handle large number of writes
- easy to use and implement on Heroku
- need to be able to filter

It sounds like you're describing Redis or Mongo. You can use the RedisToGo or MongoHQ addons on Heroku to make it easy. I've personally used MongoHQ and would recommend it to others.

For the application error piece, there's also the Hoptoad add-on for Heroku.